# ACE_OS::read_n() return 0 even some data received

Tags: c++, ace

I uses `ACE_OS::read_n()` to read some data from `stdin (ACE_STDIN)`. My code example:

```
ACE_Message_Block *head = new ACE_Message_Block(BUFSIZ);
size_t bytes_trans = 0;
ssize_t nbytes = ACE_OS::read_n(
    ACE_STDIN,
    mblk->wr_ptr(),
    mblk->size(),
    &bytes_trans);
```

If I start my program with command `./a.out <<< "hello"`, it finds EOF after data and return 0. So, I can detect data received only if check `bytes_trans` variable.

Is it correct `ACE_OS::read_n()` behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked at the [ACE doxygen documentation](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.2.5/html/libace-doc/a02179.html#aac5bac557c50fdbb08156353e05311be)

> Receive len bytes into buf from handle (uses the  call, which uses the  system call on UNIX and the  call on Win32). If errors occur, -1 is returned. If EOF occurs, 0 is returned. Whatever data has been read will be returned to the caller through bytes_transferred

Looking at the implementation (note the below code is from ACE 5.6.7... that's the source I have handy)

```
ssize_t
ACE_OS::read_n (ACE_HANDLE handle,
                void *buf,
                size_t len,
                size_t *bt)
{
  size_t temp;
  size_t &bytes_transferred = bt == 0 ? temp : *bt;
  ssize_t n = 0;

  for (bytes_transferred = 0;
       bytes_transferred < len;
       bytes_transferred += n)
    {
      n = ACE_OS::read (handle,
                        (char *) buf + bytes_transferred,
                        len - bytes_transferred);

      if (n == -1 || n == 0)
        {
          return n;
        }
    }

  return ACE_Utils::truncate_cast<ssize_t> (bytes_transferred);
}
```

So it seems that it calls multiple times to `ACE_OS::read()` accumulating the received bytes in the `bytes_transferred`

If all goes well, the return value will be the same as the contents of the `bytes_transferred`
If `read()` returns 0 or -1, `read_n()` will return 0 or -1, and the `bytes_transferred` content will be the number of bytes read so far.

Comment: Thanks. i.e. if `read_n()` returns 0, we always need to check bytes_transferred to detect any data received?

Comment: @theDilletante please check my latest edit, I've added details about the implementation that might help you.